# How to change postgresql superuser password on windows xp

Tags: postgresql, windows-xp

I want to change  postgresql superuser password on windows xp because I forgot what it is.
I have changed it last year but forgot how to do it! :D just can't remember :) somewhere (in my computer or cpanel or somewhere) i deleted the superuser and everything worked! i forgot where is that :D

Comment: The password for which user you want to change - the system "postgres" user under which the server runs or the so called superuser "postgres" which is a DB role and is created by default on cluster creation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not on Windows myself, but this has helped some. From the command line try this:

```
net user postgres postgres
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

- Right Click on my computer;
- Select Manage;
- Click on local users and groups;
- Then users;
- Right click on the username;
- Select Set Password;